# Using PHP X-Path to extract specific parts of a webpage

Tags: php, xpath, domdocument

I am after a specific value from a webapge; the product name that is in the h1 tag:

```
<div id="extendinfo_container">
  <a href="/someproduct.html"><h1><strong>Product Name</strong></h1></a>
  <div style="font-size:0;height:4px;"></div>
  <p class="text_breadcrumbs">
  <a href="/Our-Brands.html" target="_self"><img src="arrow_091.gif" align="absmiddle"/></a>
  <a href="/someproduct.html" target="_self" class="link_breadcrumbs">Product Name</a><img src="arrow_091.gif" align="absmiddle"/>
  <strong>Product Name</strong>
  <div class="dotted_line_blue">
    <img src="theme_shim.gif" height="1" width="100%" alt=" " />
  </div>
</div>
```

This is a poorly structured website with more than one h1 so I cannot simply do getElementById('h1').

I want to be as specific as possible in which element I get and this is the code I have:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTML(file_get_contents('http://url/to/website'));

// locate <div id="extendinfo_container"><a><h1><strong>(.*)</strong></h1></a> as product name
$x = new DOMXPath($doc);
$pName = $x->query('//div[@id="extendinfo_container"]/a/h1/strong');
var_dump($pName->nodeValue);
```

This is return `null`. What query do I need to use to get the content I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`query()`](http://php.net/domxpath.query) returns a [`DOMNodeList`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domnodelist.php), which doesn't have a `nodeValue` property. You have to select one element (i.e. the first):

```
$pName = $x->query('//div[@id="extendinfo_container"]/a/h1/strong')->item(0);
```

Or iterate over it:

```
foreach( $pName as $el) {
    var_dump( $el->nodeValue);
}
```

Either one of these will give you access to a [`DOMNode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php), which is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

PHP's DOM is **VERY** picky about the html you load into it. It will barf and refuse to load even slightly malformed documents.

Turn off error supression (`@$doc->loadHTML`, remove the `@`) and make sure that it's not puking on this page you're trying to analyze. Otherwise, your XPath query looks fine, and if the document does get loaded/parsed properly, it SHOULD work.

Answer (score 0):

The query works fine. I was accessing the value wrong. Here is the correct way to access the value:

`var_dump($pName->item(0)->nodeValue);`

Comment: Yep, that's what @nickb said, too.